# How to equalize the number of variables from different datasets?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, filter, merge

I have data sets from 5 different years(US stocks data sets) - 2014, 2015,2016,2017,2018. 2014 has 901 variables, while 2015- 1386, 2016-1469 and etc. I want to downsize all of them to 901 so I can easily compare them and show the movement of stocks form 2014 to 2018. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Assuming the variables are all names identically, you can read out the 901 variable names from your main data set (or define them) and then subset the other data frames to these columns.     In closing: you will find more friends here on stackoverflow, if you provide a reproducible example (some data to replicate your problem) and explain what you have tried, where you struggle, or why the output does not look like you expected.

Comment: Names of stocks are same - I mean 901 stocks is in the 1386 and I want to downsize this 1386 to 901. I have identified names of 901 stocks and used the filter:f_2014[1]

a<-print(f_2014[1], extra=TRUE)

f_2015 %>% filter(Name==a)
 But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you going, Ayaz.

1. the following defines a dataframe for 2014 and 2015 to simulate your data sets.
2. trims the 2nd data frame based on the stock-names found in the first data frame. You will notice, there are a few extra "names" and one "missing".

Note that we look for the names in `stock_2014$STOCK`. You may have them defined in another vector or pull them from elsewhere.

As you speak about filter, I assume you use the tidyverse. Here you can build your filter criteria on the names of the stock and use `%in%` to check for their occurences.

```
library(dplyr)

# simulate your data for 2 years 
stock_2014 <- data.frame(STOCK = c("A","B","C","D"), VALUE = c(12,34,56,78))
stock_2015 <- data.frame(STOCK = c("A", "A1","A2", "B", "D","D1","E"), VALUE = c(12,23,34,45,56,89,38))

stock_2015_trimmed <- stock_2015 %>% filter(STOCK %in% stock_2014$STOCK)
stock_2015_trimmed
  STOCK VALUE
1     A    12
2     B    45
3     D    56
```